# Array range being recognised as string - unable to convert to integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

i've written a function within a model to scrape a site and store certain attributes within a separate model (`story`):

```
def get_content   

          request = HTTParty.get("#{url}")

          doc = Nokogiri::HTML(request.body)

         doc.css("#{anchor}")["#{range}"].each do |entry|

            story = self.stories.new
            story.title = entry.text
            story.url = entry[:href]
            story.save

        end
```

This uses the `url`, `anchor`, and `range` attributes of a Sections variable. The range attribute is stored as an array range - i.e. `0..2` or `11..13` - however, I'm being told that it can't convert a string into a variable. I've tried storing `range` as an integer and as a string, but both fail.

I realise I could input the beginning and end of the range as two separate integers in my db, and put `["#{beginrange}".."#{endrange}"]` but this seems a messy way of doing it.

Any other ideas?  Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm if you are sure that the `range` is always a string like '`1..2`' ('`<Integer >..<Integer>`'), you can use the `eval` method:

In my IRB console:

```
1.9.3p0 :032 > (eval "1..2").each { |l| puts l }
1
2
 => 1..2 
1.9.3p0 :033 > (eval "1..2").inspect
 => "1..2" 
1.9.3p0 :034 > (eval "1..2").class
 => Range
```

**In your case:**

```
doc.css("#{anchor}")[eval(range)].each do |entry|
  #...
end
```

But `eval` is kind of dangerous. If you are sure that the `range` attribute is a Range as a String (validations and Regex are here to help), you can use `eval` without risk.

Comment: This actually fixed my problem better, it's now working! range is always a string as mentioned as I'm entering it personally into the db. Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome :) I highly recommend you to use a `validates` statement and a Regex to ensure the string passed is correctly-formated.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things I see wrong.

`["#{beginrange}".."#{endrange}"]` creates a range of characters, not a range of integers, which `Array[]` needs:

```
beginrange = 1
endrange = 2

["#{beginrange}".."#{endrange}"]
=> ["1".."2"]

[beginrange..endrange]
=> [1..2]
```

But, you're storing the representation of the array range you need as a string. If I had a string representation of a range, I'd use this:

```
range_value = '1..2'

[Range.new(*range_value.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i))]
=> [1..2]
```

Or, if there was a chance I'd encounter an exclusive-range:

```
[Range.new(*range_value.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i), range_value['...'])]
=> [1..2]

range_value = '1...2'

[Range.new(*range_value.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i), range_value['...'])]
=> [1...2]
```

Those are all good when you can't trust your Range string representation's source, i.e., the value is coming from a form or a file someone else created. If you own the incoming value, or, for convenience, stored it as a string in a database, you can easily recreate the range using `eval`:

```
eval('1..2').class
=> Range
eval('1..2')
=> 1..2
eval('1...2')
=> 1...2
```

People are afraid of `eval`, because, used unwisely, it is dangerous. That doesn't mean we should avoid using it, instead, we should use it when it's safe.

You could use a regex to check the format of the string, raise an exception if it's not acceptable, then continue:

```
raise "Invalid range value received" if (!range_value[/\A\d+\s*\.{2,3}\s*\d+\z/])
[eval(range_value)]
```